# Centos 9 missing groups or modules: nodejs

Tags: centos, repository

I want to ask question about installing nodejs but probably I had a problem with the repo.
I ran command  `dnf module list nodejs` but I got some error messages:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:15:21 ago on Tue 21 Dec 2021 02:15:57 PM WIB.
Error: No matching Modules to list
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the package the standard way. It's available in the AppStream

```
sudo dnf install nodejs
```

If you think your repos/packages are not cached properly, try cleaning the cache and then try again

```
sudo dnf clean all
sudo rm -r /var/cache/dnf
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no module for NodeJS in CentOS Stream 9. NodeJS is delivered as a single package. You can check it in the build system: https://kojihub.stream.centos.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=1363